# Guzzle installation - Client Use

Tags: php, guzzle

Forgive my ignorance but i've been struggling to get Guzzle to install in my project's folder.

I have installed Composer via it's .exe installer.
I have a composer.json file which contains the following:

```
{
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.1"
} }
```

I can run 'composer update' in which it installs Guzzle.
However, it installs "Vendor" folder which has folders 
'Guzzlehttp'-> 'guzzle' then is has 'build','src',tests' etc.

I want to use the Client object but the documentation says add:
'use GuzzleHttp\Client;' to the top of the PHP file but I don't actually have that file structure. Inside my guzzlehttp is just 'guzzle' or 'streams'folders.

Am I write in thinking Guzzle has not installed propperly? Or is there a different way to do it in Guzzle 5?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include Composer's autoloader file which takes care of loading any Composer-installed library, the autoloader file is located in the `vendor` directory.

Use the following in your code :

```
// include Composer's autoloader
require "vendor/autoload.php";

// this should work just fine now
$resp = GuzzleHttp\get("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: I swear I did this, but of course it worked perfectly. Many thanks.